# standard Save button in event detail edit page is not visible when i edit the details. How to save the record now?

Tags: lightning, detail

I have one basic question which i'm struggling to get it sorted out. Please help out with your inputs.
I have a custom profile, and the profile has all access to create, edit, and delete the event records. But still when i try editing the details of the event i am not getting Standard Save button on the page. i am seriously wondering how is it possible even.Can anyone please help to find out What must be the reason for this?

[image: Save button is missing from the marked place]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may be a browser caching issue.  Try logging in with a different browser to see if you can reproduce it.  If it doesn't happen in other browsers, then clearing your cache may work.  Or just waiting a couple of days may naturally return you to normal behavior.

If it happens in other browsers, try logging in as different users with different profiles and that will tell you if it has something to do with profile settings.

Comment: For system Admin its visible. but not for the Custom profile which i created. but i have given all needed access to this event object.

Answer (score 0):

@Amzy
Looking at the screenshot that you have attached. I seriously doubt that if that is a standard screen which has appeared.
Please make sure if this a standard detail section which appears from the page layout.

Comment: Yes it is standard detail page. which appears from the page layout.